# Asp.Net MVC 3 - How to add/execute another view file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

MVC Razor,

I have a View folder that contains

\Student\Create
\Student\Index
\Student\Delete...etc (default generated files) .

I wanted to create another view for example
\Student\Apply.cshtml

When I try to execute from e.g. Index to Apply file it shows file cannot be found.

Inside my Index file:
   @Html.ActionLink("Apply", "Apply", new { id = @Model.ID })

How do I make it work? or it is not possible to have other view files except for the default generated files..

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an action that returns that view.
That's why it's called **Action**Link.

Views are never shown on their own; they can only be returned by controller actions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created the Apply action in the Student Controller?

An actionlink points to an action which then renders a view.